# JavaScript Display Random Images

Tags: javascript, image, random

At the risk of people not being happy with me again, I will post the code that I already have. Please look at the comments and let me know where I am going wrong.

Yes this is homework, yes I have watched videos and looked at our book (JavaScript by Example) which is a horrible book by the way. I have tried to e-mail my teacher but I get nothing back. This is a 5 week intro to JavaScript class and I am obviously not understanding any of it.

```js
// create an array named imagesArray that contains the seven image file names: dog.jpg, fox.jpg, mouse.jpg, alligator.jpg, fish.jpg, parrot.jpg and cat.jpg
imagesArray = new Array(7);
imagesArray[0] = new Image();
imagesArray[0].src = new "dog.jpg";
imagesArray[1] = new Image();
imagesArray[1].src = new "fox.jpg";
imagesArray[2] = new Image();
imagesArray[2].src = new "mouse.jpg";
imagesArray[3] = new Image();
imagesArray[3].src = new "alligator.jpg";
imagesArray[4] = new Image();
imagesArray[4].src = new "fish.jpg";
imagesArray[5] = new Image();
imagesArray[5].src = new "parrot.jpg";
imagesArray[6] = new Image();
imagesArray[6].src = new "cat.jpg";

function displayImage() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random());
  document.getElementById(imagesArray[num]);
}

// create a function named displayImage
// it should not have any values passed into it
// the statement block of the displayImage should have two statements
// the first statement should generate a random number in the range 0 to 6 (the subscript values of the image file names in the imagesArray)
// the second statement display the random image from the imagesArray array in the canvas image using the random number as the subscript value
// when you generate the random number you might want to use the following formula
// a random number * the number of images in the imagesArray (Hint use the appropriate Math method to generate a random number
// remember the subscript values of the array are 0 to 6 (seven elements) zero based array
// you will have to subtract 1 from the random number generated to account for the zero based array
// In the button tag below add an onClick event handler that calls the displayImage function
// do not pass any value to the displayImage function
```

```html
<form name="imageForm">
  <table border=3>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type=button value="Display Random Image">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="blank.jpg" name="canvas">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Look at what you get when you do `Math.floor(Math.random())` in your javascript console. It will always be 0. That is because `Math.random()` always returns a decimal value between 0 and 1, and `Math.floor()` on a decimal value between 0 and 1 will always be 0. Does that help?

Comment: Where are you stuck? The comments tell you exactly what to do, and, while I appreciate it's not easy to learn something new, most of these individual requirements could be solved by simply using Google.

Comment: I honestly have tried google. Would 
    var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
work better?
What do you mean by JavaScript console? I enter everything in Sublime and then save it and then open browser in firefox.

Comment: Now you are getting somewhere :) next step is look up the documentation for `document.getElementById()`. It just returns an element from the page - now you have to do something with what it returned.

Comment: I guess my other thought was does it need to be 
document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];

Comment: You get a Javascript console when you open the Developer Tools in your web browser. (In Chrome it's called Developer Tools, in Firefox it's called Web Console.) You can enter any javascript code in the console and see the result immediately.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that even existed...

Comment: Yep. It will show you some helpful error messages, too. For instance you can't say `imagesArray[0].src = new "dog.jpg";` - because the `new` keyword can't be applied to a string like "dog.jpg". Remove the `new` keyword from those lines and keep trying.

Comment: Shouldn't you attach a click event handler to the button, and call `displayImage()` inside that event handler?

Comment: Thank you SO much itchy. I had no idea about it being right in the browser. My teaching is not going to get a very good review. I am in programing right now and being introduced to greenfoot which seems a lot like JavaScript coding.

Comment: No problem. Take a look at [this book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449390544) - it will probably get you much further in a few days than that course will get you in 5 weeks. Also [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) is a great resource for interactive learning.

Answer (score 6):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ExeHoHu/1/edit)**

HTML:

```
<!-- 
    //In the button tag below add an onClick event handler that calls the displayImage function
    //do not pass any value to the displayImage function
-->

<form name="imageForm">
  <table border=3>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="blank.jpg" name="canvas" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

JS:

```
//create an array named imagesArray that contains the seven image file names
//dog.jpg, fox.jpg, mouse.jpg, alligator.jpg, fish.jpg, parrot.jpg and cat.jpg

var imagesArray = ["dog.jpg", "fox.jpg", "mouse.jpg", "alligator.jpg", "fish.jpg", "parrot.jpg", "cat.jpg"];


//create a function named displayImage
//it should not have any values passed into it

function displayImage(){

    //the first statement should generate a random number in the range 0 to 6 (the subscript values of the image file names in the imagesArray)
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7); // 0...6
    //the second statement display the random image from the imagesArray array in the canvas image using the random number as the subscript value
    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];

}

//remember the subscript values of the array are 0 to 6 (seven elements) zero based array
//you will have to subtract 1 from the random number generated to account for the zero based array
```

If you want to make it even better ( **A+** ;) ) use:

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length+1)); // 0...6
```

Comment: You even used placehold.it... nice :)

Comment: That is why I was so confused. He is not a very good teacher at all.

Comment: @EllenHarris I re-read the *help note* he wrote about *subtract 1...*, and it comfused me too. :) best of luck and don't be scared about JS. After all (as you can see) it's fun and interesting!

Comment: I will just make sure the next class I take will be in person. You are right that JavaScript has me very interested, hopefully it will start to come to me as much as HTML has. I also want to let you know that my two other classmates thank you as well. Yep 3 beginners couldnt figure it out :(

Comment: @EllenHarris If one day you'd like to build websites or web apps, with HTML5, CSS3 you cannot do much without their younger brother **Javascript**.

Comment: I am EXTREMELY interested in the eCommerce side of the web. I have been working on adding to my employers site but from what I understand JS can be very vital for that kind of application.

Comment: @EllenHarris yes, most of applications today use JS. In that case an AJAX communication from JS to some other server-side language is an amazing stuff to give the user the best usability and have a really good interface response.

Answer (score 3):

You're very close!  Just missing a couple things.

Your random number generator will generate a number between 0-1.  To make it generate a number between 0-5 (1-6, but remember to subtract one since this is the index of your array), use this snippet:

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

You need to add an onClick attribute to your button element.

```
<input type="button" onClick="displayImage()" value="Display Random Image">
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the thread! I applied this way.

JS

```
var imgArr = ["img.jpg","name.jpg","could.jpg","be.jpg","anything.jpg"];

function displayImg(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imgArr.length));
    document.canvas.src="img/"+imgArr[num];
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" onClick="displayImg()" value="Display Random Image">
<img src="img/dog4.jpg" name="canvas" style="width:200px"/>
```