# How to have a picture randomly get chosen?

Tags: html

I have 4 pictures and what I want them to do is one of them, by random, is appeared and the others are not. How to do this?

Comment: use Math.random() javascript function to show image on Div

Comment: Hi Kevin, what have you tried so far? How do you generate this HTML?

Comment: You need javascript, this has been asked many times before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693256/javascript-display-random-images

Comment: @reto OP may not be Kevin, but may be Kevin Best's killer `;-)`

Comment: @kevinbestkiller no, don't go murdering a good name! (baba boom *ok, I'll stop there*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = choosePic;
var myPix = new Array("images/lion.jpg","images/tiger.jpg","images/bear.jpg");
function choosePic() {
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
 document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];}
```

**To display a random image:**

> var myPix = new Array("images/lion.jpg", "images/tiger.jpg", "images/bear.jpg");

Here we build an array of three images, and stuff it into the variable myPix.

> var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);

The variable called randomNum gets the value of a math expression that’s best read from the inside outwards. Math.random generates a random number between 0 and 1, which is then multiplied by myPix.length, which is the number of items in the array (in this case, it’s 3). Math.floor rounds the result down to an integer, which means that the number must be between 0 and 2.

> document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];

This says that the source of the image myPicture is set based on the array myPix, and the value at this moment is dependent on the value of randomNum.