# how add random my image url in CSS or JS..?

Tags: javascript, css

I can't find a solution for random image url in CSS or JS. Maybe I need code child in css or will automatic inserts random image for clouds..?

***update: i wish to insert my images url in css or jss, will make in random in slide different images.. i don't know how do write code ...

```js
function nuvoli() {
  let e = document.createElement("div");
  let size = Math.random() * 12;
  let duration = Math.random() * 3;

  e.setAttribute("class", "nuvolo");
  document.body.appendChild(e);
  e.style.top = Math.random() * +innerWidth + "px";
  e.style.animationDuration = 20 + duration + "s";

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(e);
  }, 20000);
}

setInterval(function() {
  nuvoli();
}, 100);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: gray;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nuvolo {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://testing.yana.lol/ita/images/bg-004.png");
  animation: animate 20s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(120%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the images in an array and pick a random index from within the bounds of that array, something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19693578/519413

Comment: You need to write what do you exactly want your code to do and what you think your current code does or what it supposed to but doesn't .

Comment: Rory McCrossan: i don't wish to index code, maybe will be inside css or js?

Comment: *"i don't know how do write code"* - then StackOverflow is the wrong site for you, do not just request code here. We debug each other's code. Hire a developer or learn how to code. Tutorials about HTML/CSS/JS are freely available on the internet. If you want to post a code (it's allowed to be wrong, just make an attempt) please do and we'll help debug it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rory McCrossan suggested you can place your images in an array and then get the random index. You can use as well css variable to change then your created divs background image. I modified a little bit your javascript to clear your body innerHTML and then reload with new image at a given interval of 20s. also made a function that change div image background, you can then change as you want

```js
let imageArray =["url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/50/50)","url(https://picsum.photos/id/2/50/50)","url(https://testing.yana.lol/ita/images/bg-004.png)"]

function changeImage(){
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)
    const rootElement = document.documentElement
    rootElement.style.setProperty('--backgroundImage',imageArray[randomIndex])
}

function nuvoli() {
    let e = document.createElement("div");
    let size = Math.random() * 12;
    let duration = Math.random() * 3;
    e.setAttribute("class", "nuvolo");
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.style.top = Math.random() * +window.innerWidth + "px";
    e.style.animationDuration = 20 + duration + "s";
    console.log(e.style.animationDuration)
  }
  
  setInterval(function() {
    nuvoli();
  },100);

  setInterval(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML=''
    changeImage();
  },20000);
```

```css
:root{
    --backgroundImage:url("https://testing.yana.lol/ita/images/bg-004.png");
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    background: gray;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .nuvolo {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: var(--backgroundImage);
    animation: animate 20s linear forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(120%);
    }
  }
```

```html
<body>
   
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but that image are same .. i want to say random images (each different image in animation)...

Comment: You are very welcome. Each 20s it repeats the animation with New random image.

Comment: Sometimes you might have twice the same image index as it is random

Comment: You Can also just call the changeImage() fonction before nuvoli() liké this you start with random image